# Rewriting partial derviative $\partial f^{-1}/\partial x$ with respect to another variable

Tags: analysis, partial-derivative

My question is very simple, yet I am unable to answer it myself. I have the following expression given:
$$\frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial \mathbf{x}},$$
where $f: \mathbb R^{d}\rightarrow\mathbb R^{d}$ is assumed to be a diffeomorphism, so the expression is well-defined. Now I want to take the partial derviate wrt the variable $u$, where $\mathbf x = f(\mathbf u)$. The result is supposed to be $$\frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{u}},$$ yet I'm unable to obtain it... This is just an intermediate result in a proof I'm going through, but I wanted to understand it.

Thank you.

Comment: Try $\frac {dx}{du}=\frac{d f(u)}{du}$ and the chain rule

Comment: @TymaGaidash Not sure on what object to apply, tbh. So if I take $\frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial u}\frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u}$ I haven't gained anything, have I?

Answer (score 0):

This is sloppy notation, and you're missing an inverse overall. Start from $f^{-1}\circ f=\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^n}$. Since $f^{-1}$ and $f$ are assumed to be differentiable, we can apply the chain rule. Let us differentiate at the point $a\in\Bbb{R}^n$; this yields:
\begin{align}
D(f^{-1}\circ f)_a&=D(\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^n})_a.
\end{align}
On the LHS, we use the chain rule, and on the RHS, we use the fact that derivatives of linear transformations at any point are themselves, to get
\begin{align}
D(f^{-1})_{f(a)}\circ Df_a&=\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^n}.
\end{align}
Now, if you want, you can repeat the argument with $f,f^{-1}$ interchanged (this time differentiating at $f(a)$), or from basic linear algebra (rank-nullity theorem) we deduce that this equation implies
\begin{align}
D(f^{-1})_{f(a)}&=[Df_a]^{-1}.
\end{align}
This is an equality of linear transformations. If you're sloppy about where the derivatives are calculated, then you can abbreviate this to $D(f^{-1})=(Df)^{-1}$; and often this is what's done in single-variable calculus notation: $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$, where of course taking the reciprocal corresponds to inversion of linear maps (or their corresponding matrix representations).

Comment: Thank you, I'd have two questions: i) Isn't $D(\text{id}_{\mathbb R^{n}})_{a} = 1$ instead of $\text{id}_{\mathbb R^{n}}$? For example in the one-dimensional case, where $\text{id}_{\mathbb R}(x) = x$, differentiating this wrt $x$ gives $1$, no? 
ii) What I'm missing in your answer is the change from $x$ to $u$, see my original question. Could you elaborate upon that?

Comment: @Hermi derivatives are linear transformations (equivalently, matrices). In the single variable case, $\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}}'(x)=1$ indeed, which means the corresponding linear transformation is $h\mapsto 1\cdot h=h$. If you find linear transformations confusing, then the Jacobian matrix of $\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^n}(x)=x$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix $I_n$. And regarding the change from $x$ to $u=f(x)$, that is taken care of in my answer by the points of evaluation: the derivative $D(f^{-1})$ is evaluated at the point $f(a)$, whereas the derivative $Df$ is taken at the point $a$.

Comment: So, things are correct as written.