# Is $\nabla f^{-1}(\mathbf{x})$ the same as $(\nabla f(\mathbf{x}))^{-1}$ for a monotone function $f$?

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, inverse, matrix-calculus, monotone-functions

Assume first that I have a one-dimensional function monotone and invertible function $y=f(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. In that case, we have:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f^{-1}(y)=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x)\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x)} \tag{1}$$

---

Now assume I have a monotone and invertible multivariate function $f(\mathbf{x}):\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$, that is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}f(\mathbf{x}) > 0$ for all dimensions $i=1,...,n$. I am interested in learning whether, anologous to the one-dimensional case, the following is true:

$$\nabla_{\mathbf{y}} f^{-1}\left(\mathbf{y}\right) = \left(\nabla_{\mathbf{x}} f\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\right)^{-1} \tag{2}$$

where $\nabla_{\mathbf{x}} f$ is the (square) matrix of partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to the dimensions of $\mathbf{x}$. In other words: are the partial derivatives of the function's inverse $f^{-1}$ the same as the inverse of the partial derivatives of the function $f$?

Comment: Your first statement is faulty. Take $f(x) = x^3$, for example. Then the left hand side is $\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}$, while the right is $\frac{1}{3}x^{-2}$. A more careful application of chain rule reveals instead the right hand side should be $\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$ instead. With a similar correction, I believe $(2)$ could be made true as well.

Comment: @Theo Bendit: Thank you for the response! Ah, I was considering the case $f(x) = 4x$ and thus didn't spot that error. So just to make sure I follow, if we define $y=f^{-1}(x)$, then the right side of (1) should read $\frac{1}{\partial/(\partial y)f(y)}$ instead? And, similarly, we get that $\nabla_{\mathbf{x}} f^{-1}(\mathbf{x}) = (\nabla_{\mathbf{y}}f(\mathbf{y}))^{-1}$ for (2)?

Comment: That's right.${}$

Comment: Note that in the 1 variable case the assumption of monotonicity is really just there to ensure that $f'(x) \neq 0$, i.e. that $f'(x)$ is invertible. Monotonicity as you have defined it is not sufficient for $\nabla f$ to be invertible when $n \geq 2$ (consider what happens if $f(x) = Ax$, where $A$ is the matrix with only $1$s). I don't have a counterexample in mind, but it's conceivable to me that $f$ could be monotonic and invertible, and yet $\nabla f$ could still fail to be invertible.

Comment: The crux is not monotonicity, but rather differentiability of your function $f$, and the existence and the existence of an inverse function $f^{-1}$, and the differentiability of the inverse. In this case, you can apply the chain rule to obtain a formula for the derivative of the inverse. Namely, the derivative of the inverse (at the appropriate point) is the inverse of the derivative (again, at the appropriate point). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4482524/568204) for more details.